# Store inner HTML Code in a Swift array

Tags: arrays, swift, swift2

I hope you can help me solving my problem. I am trying to store the inner HTML Code of a specific HTML class in a Swift array.

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<html>
<table>

<tr class="list">
<td class="list"><b>TEXT1</b></td>
<td class="list">TEXT2</td>
<td class="list">TEXT3</td>
</tr>

<tr class="list">
<td class="list"><b>TEXT4</b></td>
<td class="list">TEXT5</td>
<td class="list">TEXT6</td>
</tr>

...

</table>
</html>
```

In this case the Swift array should be:

```
let array = [
["TEXT1", "TEXT2", "TEXT3"],
["TEXT4", "TEXT5", "TEXT6"],
...
]
```

-> It stores the inner HTML Code of the HTML class "list".

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you looked at my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to parse the html and there are some nice Swift HTML Parse libraries, such as:

https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Swift-HTML-Parser

Using this as an example, you can then pull out the ul list and loop through the li tags creating an array you can use, by doing this:

```
var liArray = Array<AnyObject>()
let html = "theHtmlYouWannaParse"

//Parse HTML, handle errors
var err : NSError?
var parser = HTMLParser(html: html, error: &err)
if err != nil {
    print(err)
    exit(1)
}

var bodyNode   = parser.body

//Find and loop through ul tags
if let ulNodes = bodyNode?.findChildTags("ul") {
    for ulNode in ulNodes {
        //Find and loop through li tags
        if let liNodes = ulNode?.findChildTags("li") {
            for liNode in liNodes {
                //Add to array
                liArray.append(liNode)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you!